# How can i identify the font with used for a specific textblock inside a pdf file with multiple fonts embedded?

Tags: pdf, fonts, identify

I used 2 fonts for an webpage and printed the webpage to pdf with wkhtmltopdf. 
In the pdf file are 3 fonts embedded. 
I copied the whole text from acrobat reader to libre office writer.
In libre office are only my 2 fonts shown.

How can i identify the font with used for a specific textblock inside a pdf file?
How can i extract the text with a specific font from a pdf file?
How can i red inking the text with a specific font inside a pdf file?

Comment: You're not saying which programming language or library you want to use to accomplish these tasks. That might make it easier to help you. If your question is simply how to use an application to do this, ask again on superuser.com.

Answer (score 0):

That's three questions.

1. simplest solution: open Firefox, about:config your way to the `pdfjs.bdfBugEnabled` setting and set that to `true`. Then open your pdf file in Firefox and simply select the text you care about. The debug panel on the right will immediately show you which fonts are applied to your selected text.
2. Copy-paste, like anywhere else, or export to plain text with a pdf application.
3. I have no idea what you're asking here. If you want to edit a PDF (which I think is what you're asking) that PDF needs to have been built in a way that allows for that. If it has: use a PDF editor like Acrobat to do what you need to do. If it hasn't: you can't.

Comment: Thanks.  1. I don't see a debug panel and the Inspector from "Element inspect" shows the wrong font.

Comment: Thanks.  

1. 
I don't see a debug panel and the Inspector from "Element inspect" shows the wrong font.       

3. 
I don't want edit pdf files. 
I use wkhtmltopdf to convert html databse reports to pdf.
I want check pdf files for errors (ie wrong fonts).
 
I don't know a program like adobe acrobat for linux.

Comment: have you tried starting restart firefox after changing the value in step 1?